# Multiple Slick Sliders with Progress bars

Tags: javascript

I'm creating Slick Sliders similar to this codepen: https://codepen.io/StephenFlannery/pen/pbzOgg

Everything works great when there is just one slider, but I need to have multiple sliders and have each targeted individually, but for some reason only the last slider on the page works properly. The first 2 slider do not start.

Here is a Codepen of where I'm at: https://codepen.io/Bruggedesign/pen/BayoWeo

```
      var sliderRowIndex = 0;
      var time = 6
      var $circle,
        $sliderRow,
        $actionContent,
        $actionImages,
        $pausePlay,
        $dots,
        isPause,
        tick,
        percentTime

      $sliderRow = $('.slider-row')

      $sliderRow.each(function() {
        sliderRowIndex++

        $(this).attr('slider-row', sliderRowIndex)

        $actionImages = $('.action-slider', this)
        $actionContent = $('.action-content-slider', this)
        $pausePlay = $('.pause-play', this)
        $dots = $('.slick-dots button', this)
        $circle = $('circle.progress', this)

        $actionImages.slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: false,
          fade: true
        })

        $actionContent.slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: true,
          arrows: false,
          fade: true,
          speed: 1000,
          asNavFor: $actionImages
        })

        function startProgressbar() {
          resetProgressbar()
          percentTime = 0
          isPause = false
          tick = setInterval(interval, 10);
        }

        function interval() {
          if(isPause === false) {
            percentTime += 1 / (time+0.1);
            $circle.css({
              'stroke-dashoffset': percentTime
            });
            if(percentTime >= 156)
              {
                $actionContent.slick('slickNext');
                startProgressbar();
              }
          }
        }

        $pausePlay.on('click', function() {
          if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
            $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
            isPause = false
          } else {
            $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
            isPause = true
          }
        });

        $dots.click(function() {
            startProgressbar();
        });

        function resetProgressbar() {
          $circle.css({
            'stroke-dashoffset': 0 
          });
          clearTimeout(tick);
        }

        startProgressbar();

      })
```

```
        <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 slider-row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
            <div class="action-slider">
              <img src="/images/meet-players-1.jpg">
              <img src="/images/meet-players-2.jpg">
              <img src="/images/meet-players-3.jpg">
              <img src="/images/meet-players-4.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="action-content-slider">
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Meet Your Favorite Players</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">NFLPA VIP PARTY</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Meet Your Favorite Players</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">SUPER BOWL</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Meet Your Favorite Players</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">SUPER BOWL</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Meet Your Favorite Players</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">NFLPA VIP PARTY</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-control">
              <svg class="slider-progress-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                <title>slider-progress</title>
                <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
                    <circle class="progress" cx="26" cy="26" r="24" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
                    <circle cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" opacity="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1"/>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <button class="pause-play">
                <img src="/images/pause-icon.svg" height="11" width="11">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 slider-row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
            <div class="action-slider">
              <img src="/images/vip-events-1.jpg">
              <img src="/images/vip-events-2.jpg">
              <img src="/images/vip-events-3.jpg">
              <img src="/images/vip-events-4.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="action-content-slider">
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">VIP NFL Events</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">ROOKIE PREMIERE</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">VIP NFL Events</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">NFLPA VIP PARTY</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">VIP NFL Events</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">NFLPA VIP PARTY</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">VIP NFL Events</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">NFL DRAFT</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-control">
              <svg class="slider-progress-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                <title>slider-progress</title>
                <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
                    <circle class="progress" cx="26" cy="26" r="24" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
                    <circle cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" opacity="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1"/>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <button class="pause-play">
                <img src="/images/pause-icon.svg" height="11" width="11">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 slider-row">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
            <div class="action-slider">
              <img src="/images/gameday-1.jpg">
              <img src="/images/gameday-2.jpg">
              <img src="/images/gameday-3.jpg">
              <img src="/images/gameday-4.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="action-content-slider">
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Gameday Experiences</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">POSTGAME SIDELINE PASSES</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Gameday Experiences</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">PRO BOWL PREGAME SIDELINE PASSES</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Gameday Experiences</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">VIP TRAINING CAMP EXPERIENCE</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                  <p class="p slide-title">Gameday Experiences</p>
                  <h3 class="h3">PREGAME SIDELINE PASSES</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-control">
              <svg class="slider-progress-circle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
                <title>slider-progress</title>
                <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
                  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
                    <circle class="progress" cx="26" cy="26" r="24" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
                    <circle cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" opacity="0.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1"/>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </svg>
              <button class="pause-play">
                <img src="/images/pause-icon.svg" height="11" width="11">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you show the HTML you're using with this?

Comment: @j3py just updated with HTML included

Comment: Can you share a codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: @ssBarBee Just added, thanks! https://codepen.io/Bruggedesign/pen/BayoWeo